# Unable to pipe template variables in Grafana 4.5.2

Tags: grafana, prometheus, grafana-templating

In Grafana, I have a template variable which I want to pipe for running a prometheus query.

`query{key='value1|value2|value3'}` works for me.

Whereas, I have a template variable (Type: Query with Prometheus datasource and filtered with regex) called `$t_var` which can take values `['value1','value2','value3']`

But, when I try the following query, I don't get any results:

`query{key=~'${t_var:pipe}'}`

Look at the **pipe** section in Grafana documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/

Comment: You could use either Grafana's query inspector (somewhere to the right of the query, if this a query from a panel) or your browser's network inspector to compare what the HTTP query looks like in the two cases. That should help you figure out why the behavior is different.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AlinSînpălean.

I have checked that with "Query inspector" tool too. Ideally, ```${t_var:pipe}``` should have given me ```value1|value2|value3``` according to the "advanced formatting" that Grafana claims. Instead, it is still showing as ```${t_var:pipe}```. This didn't change even if I put that outside of quotes as well.

Comment: @AlinSînpălean I have found the solution for my problem and updated that in answer to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem without using any advanced formatting techniques such as pipe, json, csv, etc., as mentioned in this [Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/).

Change required was very simple:

Instead of trying to concatenate list of template variables by pipe, I passed the whole template variable inside the query and also made 'Legend' as the template variable.

For example, my modified query is as follows:

`query{key=~'[[t_var]]'`
Legend format is `{{t_var}}`